# typeahead.js - Uncaught TypeError: this.displayText(...).toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I've been messing around with [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) templates. No matter what I do, I keep getting the following error:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** this.displayText(...).toLowerCase is not a function in typeahead.min.js:2

My JavaScript looks as following:

```
$('#search-field').typeahead({
    display: 'value',
    templates: {
        suggestion: function(data) {
            return '<p><strong>' + data.value + '</strong> – ' + data.titleid + '</p>';
        }
    },
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get(root + '/api/search.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
            console.log('data:' + data); //outputs the JSON correctly.
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            return process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Where /api/search.php looks like:

```
[{"value":"Name1","titleid":"Test1"},{"value":"Name2","titleid":"Test2"},{"value":"Name3","titleid":"Test3"}]
```

I've tried copying code from other examples directly into mine, sometimes even the whole piece, but that didn't solve it either, even though it did work in the example.

How can I solve this, and get the template to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Used the typeahead.js bundle for the other plugins used in the code below.

```
var search = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/api/search.php?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});

$('#search-field').typeahead(null, {
    display: 'titleid',
    source: search,
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
            'no results found.',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{titleid}}</div>')
    }
});
```

What I've learned from this? typeahead.js is a tough plugin to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this issue](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/issues/170) and [this issue](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/issues/93) on GitHub. It appears that your objects in the `source` must have a `name` property, or you must define a `displayText` function yourself. The second issue linked has a response which states:

> The document should make clear that: "You can add all the properties you wish on your objects, as long as you provide a "name" attribute OR you provide your own displayText method."

And the solution is to add a `displayText` function to your `typeahead` options, like this:

```js
$('#search-field').typeahead({
    ...
    displayText: function (item) { return item.value; }
    ...
});
```

Where `item.value` can be whatever property you wish to display.

Comment: Hello Matt, thanks for your reply. It does seem to solve the error, however it 'ignores' the `suggestion` template. Any way to get that to work?

Comment: Hmm. I see some sources that say `displayKey` rather than `displayText` and you would do it as `displayKey: 'value'`. Could you try that and see what happens?

Comment: Removing `displayText` and adding `displayKey: 'value'` didn't seem to do the trick either. I get the error described in my question again. :(

Comment: You don't have any other errors logged in the console? It just ignores the suggestion template?

Comment: When I used your answers' example, it worked correctly, it indeed just ignored the template.

Comment: Could you post a StackBlitz or similar with an example that reproduces this?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I've posted an answer that fixed the issue for me. Thanks for the help.